# How to create a Bech32 address from a public key?

Tags: address, bech32-address

What are the steps to create a Bech32 address from an ECDSA public key? Bitcoin wiki has a nice [step-by-step guide](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Technical_background_of_version_1_Bitcoin_addresses) to create an address from a public key but what about Bech32 addresses? I've read BIP173 but I don't understand what to give as an input.

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://github.com/sipa/bech32/tree/master/ref/python

Comment: @pors I have seen this repo but I do not know what to input. I understand I am to use the bech32_encode function but what do I put in there? The public key? The hash160? the P2WSH? How do I create that?

Comment: Welcome to Bitcoin.SE! For @pors, you can help by posting your expanded comments as an answer and possibly including some 'how to use' information.

Comment: nullius has created a tool in december, to play with bech32 addresses in C. Easy usable, and code is documented as well. See here: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=2664728.msg27178628#msg27178628

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ok, I figured out how to do it.

You need 3 pieces of information to construct the bech32 address.

- `hrp`: the human-readable part. This is `bc` for mainnet and `tb` for testnet
- `witver`: the witness version. This is `0` at the moment represented by the byte `0x00` but it can go up to `16` when they add more versions.
- `witprog`: the witness programm. In case you want a Pay-to-witness-public-key (P2WPK) address which is the most common ones, this is the 20-byte hash160 of the **compressed** public key i.e `ripemd160(sha256(compressed_pub_key))`. In case you want a Pay-to-witness-script-hash (P2WSH) address, this is the 32-byte sha256 of the scriptPubKey which is the script that will need to evaluate to True for someone to be able to spend the output. More on this in [BIP141](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0141.mediawiki#witness-program)

Once you have those 3 pieces, you can use the encode function in one of the [reference implementations](https://github.com/sipa/bech32/tree/master/ref)

I have put together a small [pure Python library](https://github.com/mcdallas/cryptotools) for anyone interested how all this stuff works behind the hood.

Comment: Can you add some text vectors here or point to your test vectors?

Comment: @Jus12 https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0173.mediawiki#Test_vectors