# how to generate bech32/segwit address from pubkey in golang

Tags: address, segregated-witness, bech32-address, go-lang

I am trying to generate bech32/segwit address in golang with the following code:

```
var pubkey *btcec.PubKey
address, err := btcutil.NewAddressPubKey(pubkey.SerializeCompressed(), chainParams)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
address.SetFormat(btcutil.PKFCompressed)
bech32Bytes, err := bech32.ConvertBits(address.ScriptAddress(), 8, 5, true)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
segwitaddr, err := bech32.Encode("tb", bech32Bytes)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

and also more simply

```
var e *hdkeychain.ExtendedKey
address, err := e.Address(chainParams)
bech32Bytes, err := bech32.ConvertBits(address.ScriptAddress(), 8, 5, true)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
segwitaddr, err := bech32.Encode("tb", bech32Bytes)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

But neither `segwitaddr` generated match the bip84 address I got from https://iancoleman.io/bip39/. What is wrong with the code above or how to properly get a bech32 address from a pub key?

I have looked into another [post](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/70507/how-to-create-a-bech32-address-from-a-public-key) on the same question, but could not figure out how to prepare the data needed in golang. More specifically, I am confused in preparing the input `[]byte` to call [`bech32.Encode()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/btcsuite/btcutil/bech32#Encode) and using [`bech32.ConvertBits()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/btcsuite/btcutil/bech32#ConvertBits).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer thanks to [modood/btckeygen](https://github.com/modood/btckeygen).

Here is the relevant code extracted from the repo.

```
witnessProg := btcutil.Hash160(pubkey.SerializeCompressed())
addressWitnessPubKeyHash, err := btcutil.NewAddressWitnessPubKeyHash(witnessProg, chainParams)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
address := addressWitnessPubKeyHash.EncodeAddress()
```