# Bitaddress.org gives me legacy address instead of Bech32 address

Tags: private-key, public-key, bitcoin-wallet-app, bech32-address

I have my private key, but when I put it into bitaddress.org, it gives me a legacy address (starting with "1") and not the Bech32 address (starting with "bc1") that I was expecting. My client has only Bech32 receiving addresses and I understandably don't want to lose my coin. How can I get the correct Bech32 receiving BTC address from the BTC private key that I already have?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a Bech32 address from a public key?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/70507/how-to-create-a-bech32-address-from-a-public-key)

Answer (score 1):

You can import a private key into the Bitcoin Core wallet using the importprivkey [RPC](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.18.0/rpc/wallet/importprivkey/). You can then send the funds associated with that private key to a new address controlled by whatever wallet client you are using.